# Difference between code signing target and project

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, ios-provisioning

I noticed that in Xcode I can set the Entitlements and Code signing settings both on:

- the Project (double click on the top item in Groups & File, which has the name of the project)
- the Target (under Targets, double click on your project name).

What's the difference between these two? I know that with header paths, one tends to override the other (without warning of course...).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Target settings override Project settings. Project settings are valid for all Targets where the setting has not been overridden.