# Why should we specify the code signing identity twice?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, sign

One is in the project, the other is in the target.

Which one is actually used?

Comment: Another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3797376/1431728

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project that weather you are using application with single target or with multiple target.

If you have only single target in application, then you need to add it from Project and click on code signing in target and delete it. So, from next time project change will reflect on target change.

Now, if you have multiple target in your application, then you need to set it from target.

Hope, it will clear your vision regarding code signing .

Comment: So code signing identity on target will override code signing identity on target. In other word, I can just ignore the project.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus yes. if you have single target, then project change will reflect on target change after click on delete from target.